# Secure way to allow a specific PHP script to read/write a directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, centos

I have a php script that needs to create/delete files within the /www/mydata directory (using centos+linux+apache).

I gave the "apache" user ownership of www/mydata to allow this.

Is that secure enough?  Is there a better method?  I would much prefer that ONLY the specific script have "ownership" of www/mydata and only while it's running, in case someone is getting up to shenanigans.

Can that be done, or am I stuck giving the apache user all these privs?

Edit: to forestall a few obvious answers, I have attempted to have the script create the directory (it can't) and I've also attempted to set the directory permissions in the script on the fly using PHP's chmod (no deal).

Comment: So there are other users on your server who pose a security risk? Can you elaborate?

Comment: No, not at all-- no other users.  What I am most worried about is someone remote manages to get control of the apache user through some kind of exploit, via a browser, and then can modify that folder at will.

I don't even know if that's far-fetched or not.  I have seen some things in my day.

Comment: What you want is, in principle, impossible. You cannot let PHP, as part of Apache, manipulate files, and, at the same time, make these files completely inaccessible to Apache. I also don't believe such an exploit is likely, unless you provide it. In other words; If there are no other users on the server, but you, then don't worry about this.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need to know-- whether I'm just being overly paranoid or not.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it answered.

Comment: Don't care about marking, just glad I could help. I am still unclear about how secure you want these files to be? For instance: No file is very secure at a hosting provider, since the provider always has root access. Do you know what they are doing? That's a gaping hole right there.

Answer (score 0):

The "Apache" user you mentioned can be ANYONE from the Internet that running the script. If you want to secure the "www/mydata" directory, you can try to check the user's privilege before they execute the actual "create/delete" actions.